# Angular FlexLayout Cards same Layout

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I'm quite new to the subject and am currently in the first attempts of a project. So I hope you can help me :)

I am using a FlexLayout with mat-cards and the first three elements are working as expected. However, the last element has not the same heigh as the others and I'm not able to fix this.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
 <div fxFlex="20%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-doughnutcard></ra-doughnutcard>
 </div>
 <div fxFlex="20%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-doughnutcard></ra-doughnutcard>
 </div>
 <div fxFlex="40%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-linecard></ra-linecard>
 </div>
 <div fxFlex="20%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-listcard></ra-listcard>
 </div>
</div>
```

Listcard-Component-html:

```
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z5">
 <mat-card-title>
  <h5>Text</h5>
 </mat-card-title>
 <mat-card-content>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items"> {{ item }} </mat-list-item>
 </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Without the Tag ra-listcard it seems working. I tried also the stretch aligment of FlexLayout without success. I think ra-listcard as the parent container is setting the wrong height, how can I fix this issue?

In CSS is only h5 size and text aligment set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Clemens Sums answer I have understood how to set properties on parent containers and I found a solution for my issue:

```
:host {
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
}

mat-card {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to declare the following in the `ra-listcard` components styles:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}

mat-card {
    height: 100%;
}
```

See https://angular-9-material-starter-5k4ugj.stackblitz.io for a simplified version.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **`fxFlex`** in your tags so that they take up all the available space, like this:

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap="16px grid">
 <div fxFlex="20%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-doughnutcard fxFlex></ra-doughnutcard>
 </div>
 <div fxFlex="20%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-doughnutcard fxFlex></ra-doughnutcard>
 </div>
 <div fxFlex="40%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-linecard fxFlex></ra-linecard>
 </div>
 <div fxFlex="20%" fxFlex.sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
  <ra-listcard fxFlex></ra-listcard>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]